# How do I monetize my Tor-Exit Node?

Tags: exit-relays

I want to monetize my traffic that goes through my Tor -Exit Node, to maintain the cost that comes with running an Exit Node.

How do I do that?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible unless you sell statistics of the traffic, and maybe you won't gain so much. My suggestion is that you open a node in Sentinel dVPN and sell your bandwidth for the criptocurrency Sentinel dVPN uses, so people wanting private browsing would benefit from it. (I'm not making spam or something like it, I'm just suggesting an idea I had).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to charge users of your Tor relay. The Tor network is fundamentally designed for Tor relay operators to donate their services to Tor users.

If you wanted to monetize your relay, you would have to setup something like your own private Tor network, where you can charge people for access (or join a network which already does this, like alpominth in the comment mentioned).
If you do this though, it wouldn't be a Tor relay anymore ;)

Comment: Who said anything about charging?
There are tons of ways to gain money through traffic I am just not aware of them.